# Estou tentando fazer um switch case com mais de uma variável, mas não sei como fazer funcionar, alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: c#

Quero atribuir essas 4 variáveis ao switch case entretanto quando vou determinar o case com as 4 variáveis ele não aceita, fala:
Erro    CS0029  Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "bool" em "(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)"   Calcular distancias

```
public class calculo
{
    public void calcular(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {

        switch(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        {
            case x1 == x2 && y1 != y2:
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não é possível de fazer, o `switch` usar um único "comutadaor" ou valor que deve ser testado, e é sempre igualdade, não se pode combinar condições como `x1 == x2 && y1 != y2`.

Por exemplo:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int aleatorio = rnd.Next(1,4);

switch (aleatorio)
{
   case 1:  // significa caso aleatorio igual a 1
       Console.WriteLine("Um");
       break;
   case 2:
       Console.WriteLine("Dois");
       break;
     ....
}
```

Sugiro que leia mais sobre [Como funciona o switch](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Mesmo utizando `when` (por exemplo `switch(x1) case 10 when x1 < y1`), não seria possível fazer com `switch`, o seu exemplo é um caso que pode ser tratado com `if`, por exemplo:

```
if (x1 == x2 && y1 != y2)
{
    ... comandos ...
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas teria algum comando parecido com o switch que faz o que eu quero?
Pois se eu usar if seriam muitos, pois tem varias condições.

Comment: não tem, mas pode usar if/else if e ir adicionando as condições