# Múltiplos cases no switch com C# 8

Tags: c#, sintaxe, switch, pattern-matching

Ao ver [essa pergunta sobre múltiplas condições no `switch`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491935/estou-tentando-fazer-um-switch-case-com-mais-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-mas-n%C3%A3o-sei-como-f), me fez lembrar de um problema que tive e não consegui resolver.

No C# 8,  [foi incluída uma nova sintaxe para o `switch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression):

```
int num = ObterUmNumero();

var descricao = num switch
{
    0 => "Zero",
    1 => "Um",
    2 => "Dois",
    _ => "Indefinido"
};
```

É uma *syntax sugar* e fica limpo e claro o código, mas me ocorreu o seguinte, como faço para aplicar um valor a múltiplos `cases`?

Por exemplo, como fazer com que essa sintaxe mais convencional funcione?

```
var descricao = string.Empty;
switch(num)
{
    case -1:
    case 0:
        descricao = "Invalido";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é possível fazer com que dois padrões caiam no mesmo case. Note que a [expressão switch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) é diferente da [declaração (*statement*) switch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

A maneira mais simples de atingir o que você deseja é criar uma expressão que atenda os dois casos.

Em C# 9 isso fica bem mais simples porque é possível usar o padrão disjuntivo `or`.

```cs
int num = ObterUmNumero();

var descricao = num switch
{
    -1 or 0 => "Invalido",
    1 => "Um",
    2 => "Dois",
    _ => "Indefinido"
};
```

O *pattern matching* do C# 9 também permite usar [padrões relacionais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3#relational-patterns).

```cs
var descricao = num switch
{
    < 1 => "Inválido", 
    1 => "Um",
    2 => "Dois",
    _ => "Indefinido"
};
```

[Veja mais sobre as melhorias do *pattern matching* no C# 9 na documentação.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements)

Comment: muito bom, como estou usando o `C#9`, o `-1 or 0 => "Invalido"` ficou perfeito

Comment: @RicardoPontual Sim, o _pattern matching_ do C# tá ficando muito bom.

Answer (score 6):

A primeira questão sobre o assunto que precisamos entender é sobre a sintaxe das duas construções.

Apesar de ambas usarem a mesma palavra chave elas são completamente diferentes. Aproveitaram o nome para não ter que criar outra palavra reservada na linguagem, oque provavelmente quebraria várias códigos existentes, mas não ter usado um `match` fez muita gente entender errado essa diferença.

O primeiro `switch` é um açúcar sintático para `if` e para todos os efeitos ele é o mesmo que um `if`. O `switch` tradicional não é um `if`, ele é uma *jump list*, é uma otimização de desvio de execução baseando em uma tabela de valores possível, por isso ele é bem limitado no que pode colocar ali.

Isto é explicado em [Como funciona o switch por baixo dos panos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/101). A linguagem é diferente, mas todas que possuem esse mecanismo da forma correta trabalham essencialmente da mesma forma.

Mas o C# foi um pouco mais esperto e conseguiu mesmo no caso do *pattern matching* criar uma *jump list* otimizada onde dá para fazer isto. E até de uma forma mais organizada do que era feito com o `switch` tradicional.

É possível ver que o [CIL tem instrução específica para montar o `switch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.switch?view=net-5.0&?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e isso gerará um código mais adequado para a situação. [Veja no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIEyYIwHZ0BvAWACgBIbHUyisAO2HQYFcBbdAXnQHkAjYAFMATgFV2AOQ6iA9gAoAlAG5yFCgDcAhiPQwhAZwDGIsEa2zuLDugMB3MMCMALYmvUAGbgD50AIgAtOT8odFwffwkQ9BwuXz8AEVkwA2iAfQi/AEkGfQAzRjAYWT93AF9VSjK1ZFwANnRGZgFhcSkZEQVFCNxKsqA). O JITter será o responsável por montar o código real mais adequado para executar a necessidade. Perceba que embora o compilador não faça nada nele em si, existe a possibilidade do JITter fazer mais otimizações, por isso foi criada uma instrução no CIL. Então não podemos afirmar que o jeito mais *match* do `switch` do C# seja claramente ineficiente, vai depender do cenário específico e da implementação do JITter.

Já o `switch` tradicional é gerado pelo compilador criando a tal *jump list* "na mão". [Veja no **SharpLab**.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIEyYIwHZ0BvAWACgBIbHUs9eh+gNwEMAndGAUwGcBjNmD4sA9ugC86AERSA3OQoVWHAHYBXALYT0AeQBGwLmwCqGgHKajIgBQBKeXUYMeAdzDA+AC2vqNt4uROQejCPFzoALS4IIHBjKHhAAwxjnFB3PyCwmKSUgCSKqwQYDAicrFpTnpsXCwA1g5xAL4KLZTIuABs6GAqwLoGRqYWGlZ2EgB86LgOTUA).

Veja que a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) distingue claramente a declaração `switch` da expressão de *match*. Essa sintaxe de *match* foi introduzida em C# 6, e vem melhorando a cada versão.

A resposta do Leandro mostra como fazer com o *match* (expressão `switch`) para que aceite dois valores até o C# 8 (começando no 6 obviamente). Para todos os efeitos é um `if`, não há otimização específica alguma, nem pelo compilador (claro que ele faz o melhor que pode) e nem será feito depois pelo JITter. [Veja no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIEyYIwHZ0BvAWACgBIbHUs9eh+sAO2HWYFcBbdAXnQDyAI2ABTAE4BVLgDluEgPYAKAJQBuco0YA3AIbj0MUQGcAxuLCndCvu27pjAdzDBTAC2Kat3vQbDpHN1FmdH9efgBaXHRERFC+fgAGPgA+dAAiAElmbQBDiDAYBXSoL29GaN409OkSsvL6HCqMgBEFMGM6ugaGAH1UjOyjADMWQuL6xgBfDUop8ipcADZQ1kERCWk5LkVVAdxZqaA==).

Eu só não gosto muito do outro exemplo que ele montou porque gera alocações de memória desnecessária. Mas isso é colateral ao assunto que tratamos aqui.

A resposta do LINQ mostra uma outra forma de resolver o mesmo e que está disponível em C# 9 em diante. Ela é bem mais fácil de ler e escrever. Ela também gera um código diferente final podendo fazer as otimizações pelo JITter, portanto ela é bem mais interessante do que simplesmente ficar mais "bonitinho". [Veja no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIEyYIwHZ0BvAWACgBIbHUyisAO2HQYFcBbdAXnQHkAjYAFMATgFV2AOQ6iA9gAoAlAG5yFCgDcAhiPQwhAZwDGIsEa2zuLDugMB3MMCMALYmvXoAtLnSzdABm4APnQAIgBJBg0AQ4gwGFlQqHQfLhDQiST0HDSwgBFZMAMsgH1gsMj9ADNGeMT3AF9VSga1ZFwANnRGZgFhcSkZEQVFctxmhqA===). Note que ele tende criar uma *jump list* mesmo neste caso, de uma forma possivelmente igual ou melhor que o `switch` tradicional, só não há garantias pela linguagem, dependerá do JITter.

De fato se olharmos o código final JITtado na implementação usada, gera um código bem eficiente. [Veja no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgNAJiA1AHwAIGYAEqBM2CMA7JgN4CwAUAJC57nVUCWAdsJswK5SYC8mA8gCNgAUwBOAVSgA5LuID2ACgCUAbkpUqANzBjMcERADGYxkbDze7LpggB3RsCMALUhs2YAtPkzy9ABl4APkwAIgBJZi0AQ4AbRjh5UJhMHx4Q0KlkzDx0sIAReUYIbIB9YLDIgwAzFgSk9wBfdWpGjVR8ADZMFjYhUUkZOTElZQr8FsagA=). Me parece mais ou menos tão eficiente quanto o `switch` tradicional (olhando por cima). Mas se você precisa do máximo de otimização precisa acompanhar o resultado final, não pode confiar no compilador sempre.

Comment: *"Apesar de ambas usarem a mesma palavra chave elas são completamente diferentes. Aproveitaram o nome para não ter que criar outra palavra reservada na linguagem"* eu pensei a mesma coisa quando vi essa feature :) Boa análise, especialmente pelos links do SharpLab

Answer (score 5):

Nesse exemplo simples você pode declarar uma variável e utilizar outros operadores de comparação. Como por Exemplo:

```
  int num = ObterUmNumero();

  var descricao = num switch
    {
        var i when (i <= 0)  => "Inválido",
        1 => "Um",
        2 => "Dois",
        _ => "Indefinido"
    };
```

No caso de várias opções, você pode adicionar várias condições também:

```
int num = ObterUmNumero();

var descricao = num switch
{
    var i when (i == -1 || i == 0) => "Inválido",
    1 => "Um",
    2 => "Dois",
    _ => "Indefinido"
};
```

Também é interessante como pode ser usado para outros tipos de tratamento quando utilizamos uma `string`, como uma simples comparação utilizando o contains ou até mesmo padrões mais complexos utilizando regex.

```
string mensagem = "Erro: Ocorreu uma falha no sistema";

var tipoMensagem = mensagem switch
{
    var i when (i.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("sucesso")) => "Sucesso",
    var i when (i.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("erro")) => "Erro",
    _ => "Informação"
};
```

Comment: fiquei em dúvida no segundo exemplo: `var i when (i == -1 || i == 0) => "Inválido",` o switch está avaliando a variável `num`, se declarar a variável `i`, qual vai ser a relação dela com a `num`? ela teria o valor de `num`?

Comment: mesmo com a declaração de `var i`, para ela vai ser atribuído o valor de `num`, acaba funcionando mais como um container para a comparação do `when`. Assim como já tínhamos anteriormente na sintaxe completa do `switch` . `switch (num){ case int i when (i <= 0): texto = "inválido";}`

Comment: Aqui segue a explicação https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#case-labels